# How to use mkl_sparse_?_mv in MKL?

Tags: intel-mkl

Can anyone give me an example of multiplying a sparse matrix by a vector using `mkl_sparse_?_mv`? Specifically, how to define the sparse matrix A?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Testing sparse blas\n");
    sparse_operation_t operation = SPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE;
    float alpha = 1.0;
    float beta = 0.0;
    sparse_matrix_type_t A_type = SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL;

    int m = (int) pow(2,3);
    int n = (int) pow(2,5);

    float * x = calloc(n,sizeof(float));
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        x[i] = i*2+1;
    }
    float * y = calloc(m*n,sizeof(float));

    // How to define A?
    mkl_sparse_s_mv(operation, alpha, A, SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL, x, beta, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Matrix `A` should be created via one of `mkl_sparse_?_create_?` routines. For example, if you have a CSR sparse matrix, you should call [`mkl_sparse_?_create_csr`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/inspector-executor-sparse-blas-routines/matrix-manipulation-routines/mkl-sparse-create-csr.html) to convert it into the internal representation (`sparse_matrix_t`):

```
constexpr MKL_INT M = 5;
constexpr MKL_INT N = 5;
constexpr MKL_INT NNZ = 13;

float   csrVal[NNZ]      = { /* ... */ };
MKL_INT csrColInd[NNZ]   = { /* ... */ };
MKL_INT csrRowPtr[M + 1] = { /* ... */ };

sparse_matrix_t csrA;
mkl_sparse_s_create_csr(&csrA, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO, N, M,
    csrRowPtr, csrRowPtr + 1, csrColInd, csrVal);
```

and then use it for `mkl_sparse_s_mv`:

```
float x[N]  = { /* ... */ };
float y[N]  = { /* ... */ };
float alpha = /* ... */, beta = /* ... */;

matrix_descr descrA;
descrA.type = SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL;

mkl_sparse_optimize(csrA);
mkl_sparse_s_mv(SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, alpha, csrA, descrA, x, beta, y);
mkl_sparse_destroy(csrA);
```

This code was taken from examples provided within MKL distribution. You can find it in `$MKLROOT/examples/examples_core_c.tgz/spblasc/source/sparse_csrmv.c`.

Comment: It's actually pretty confusing to see references such as `$MKLROOT/examples/examples_core_c.tgz/spblasc/source/sparse_csrmv.c` as it is certainly not clear where to find this, it looks like MKL has been overhauled several times since this post was written, but for whatever reason the API has not changed much. In this case, it may make sense (in the future) to just paste the entire contents of the referenced c file. At least your answer has enough detail to piece together an answer, but it would be more complete if the reference c file.